# Indian rupee symbol

Tags: symbols

India has recently introduced a new symbol for its currency, the Indian rupee -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign. How can I typeset this in TeX / LaTeX?

Comment: They say it might take around 18 months, to get into Unicode.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Linux Libertine](http://ctan.org/pkg/libertine) v4.8.4 already supports the new rupee sign. From the [changelog](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/libertine/doc/fonts/libertine/ChangeLog.txt):

> Changes to version 4.8.0 regular(-) &
>   italic(/) & capitals (C) (20100430)
>
> ...
>
> - new Indian Rupee symbol uni20A8

Comment: Wow!  That's _fast_ (the font makers, that is).

Comment: Note that U+20A8 may have been an ill-advised choice to put the new rupee sign, as it is the code point for the old rupee sign, that looks like “Rs”. If the proposal to add it to Unicode goes through (http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc2/wg2/docs/n3862.pdf), and it most likely will, it should get position U+20B9.

Answer (score 20):

Today the package [`tfrupee`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tfrupee) has been released on CTAN, providing LaTeX support for the [techfat font](http://techfat.blogspot.com/) containing the Indian rupee. It's been converted to Adobe Type 1 format.

Answer (score 11):

See this page for all details: http://www.csa.iisc.ernet.in/~uday/rupee-latex.html

Here are the key steps.

1. Download the tfrupee package available at CTAN. It's a 1.5 MB zip file named `tfrupee.zip`.
2. Run the following to install `tfrupee`.

   ```
   unzip tfrupee.zip  
   cd tfrupee/  
   sudo cp -rv fonts/type1/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/  
   sudo cp -rv fonts/afm/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/afm/  
   sudo cp -rv fonts/tfm/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/  
   sudo cp -rv fonts/map/dvips/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/  
   sudo cp -rv fonts/source/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/  
   sudo cp -rv tex/latex/tfrupee/ /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/  
   sudo texhash  
   sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=tfrupee.map
   ```
3. Test it with this simple tex file.

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}  
   \usepackage{tfrupee}  
   \begin{document}  
   \rupee~7,000  
   \end{document}
   ```

With `pdflatex`, or `latex`/`dvips`, you shouldn't see any messages from tex about inability to create bitmap fonts for `tfrupee`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it should be mostly self-contained and not just contain a link to an external site. Such links can break over time. It would be best you list here the basic part of the linked solution.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). Short passages can be marked using backticks `\``. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: Note that code in lists must be indented by 8 spaces.

Comment: This is in `texlive-fonts-extra` in Debian wheezy (stable) TeX Live 2012.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, then the [New Computer Modern](https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern) fonts offer the Devanagari script, which contains the Indian Rupee Sign U+20B9. You can use it in the following way. You can use it in math mode as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[default, newcmbb]{fontsetup}
\newfontfamily\devanagari[%
Script=Devanagari,%
% Renderer=Harfbuzz% Optionally for LuaTeX
]{NewCM10Devanagari-Book.otf}

\newcommand{\rs}{{\text{\devanagari ₹}}}

\begin{document}
    \$1 = \rs 83.19, \(\$ 1 = \rs 83.19\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Indian Rupee sign]